# About response function in a server file

Tags: ros, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am a newer to ROS. I defined a srv file:

```
float64 HeadYawSet
float64 HeadPitchSet
---
float64 HeadYaw
float64 HeadPitch
```

I am going to write a server to get the value from "HeadYawSet" and "HeadPitchSet" simultaneously acquire joint data to put them in HeadYaw and HeadPitch. And my code is below:

```
def Receive(req):
#Motion= ALproxy("ALMotion")
    names = "HeadYaw"
    fractionMaxSpeed = 0.1
    useSensors  = True 
    HeadYaw = Motion.getAngles(names, useSensors)
    Motion.setAngles(names, req.HeadYawSet,fractionMaxSpeed)
    names = "HeadPitch"
    HeadPitch=Motion.getAngles(names, useSensors)
    Motion.setAngles(names, req.HeadPitchSet, fractionMaxSpeed)
    req.HeadYaw= HeadYaw;
    req.HeadPitch= HeadPitch;
    #print "HeadYawSet:" %(req.HeadPitchSet)
    #return headResponse( [HeadYaw, HeadPitch] )
```

##ROS is responsible for communicating the sub-processes with naoqi, it reads any data from the robot and give them to all the sub
##processes and it gets all the data from sub-processes and send them to the robot. NAOQI---ROS---PROCESSES

```
def receive_server():
    rospy.init_node('head')
    s = rospy.Service('receiving_on_head', head, Receive)
    print "Ready to receive the head joint values"

    rospy.spin()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    receive_server()
```

it gave me strange errors when I run my client code in C++
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/ros_comm/clients/rospy/src/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py", line 600, in _handle_request
response = convert_return_to_response(self.handler(request), self.response_class)
File "head.py", line 34, in Receive
req.HeadYaw= HeadYaw;
AttributeError: 'headRequest' object has no attribute 'HeadYaw'
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1310328838.362102] Error processing request: 'headRequest' object has no attribute 'HeadYaw'
None**

Can anybody help me a bit here? Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10549/about-response-function-in-a-server-file./) by [Gauss Lee](https://answers.ros.org/users/815/gauss-lee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2011-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You probably want something like:

```
def Receive(req):
#Motion= ALproxy("ALMotion")
    names = "HeadYaw"
    fractionMaxSpeed = 0.1
    useSensors  = True 
    HeadYaw = Motion.getAngles(names, useSensors)
    Motion.setAngles(names, req.HeadYawSet,fractionMaxSpeed)
    names = "HeadPitch"
    HeadPitch=Motion.getAngles(names, useSensors)
    Motion.setAngles(names, req.HeadPitchSet, fractionMaxSpeed)

    # new code 
    resp = headResponse()
    resp.HeadYaw= HeadYaw
    resp.HeadPitch= HeadPitch
    return resp
```

Assuming that your service is in a file called head.srv

Note that for headResponse to be defined you may also need to add a line like this towards the top of your source:

```
from your_pkg.srv import *
```

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is that you are referring to the request, but you should build a response and return that instead of changing the request. This should be very similar to the AddTwoInts tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-07-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1